# selectize js está atrás do input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou usando o selectize e estou com um problema o imput está por trás da minha tabela e os estados só o primeiro está no fundo branco os demais estão transparentes alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código no Js

```
$(".js-combo-uf")
.on(
        "change",
        function() {
            var id_estado = $(this).val();
            $
            .ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/listacidades",
                data: ({
                    parametroBusca: id_estado,
                    tipoBusca: 'uf'
                }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var text = "<select class='form-control' name='cidade' id='selecionar-estados' ><option value=''>Cidade</option>";
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        text += '<option value="' +
                        data[i] + '">' +
                        data[i] + '</option>';
                    }
                    text += '</select>';
                    $(".js-combo-cidade").html(text);
                    $('.js-combo-roteiro').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                    $('#selecionar-estados').selectize();

                }
            });
        });
```

as bibliotecas que instalei foi:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/selectize.js}"></script>
```

Comment: Coloque também o HTML e o CSS. Pode ser problema de estilos.

Answer (score 0):

faltou adicionar os css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/selectize.css}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css}" />
```

após adiciona-los, funcionou.

obs: a documentação deles não são bem explicáveis.